# Partial Derivatives and Differentiability of a piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

this is my first post on this wonderful forum.
I'd like to thank all of you for the help you're going to give me. 
I was doing an exercise, but I'm not sure the solution is entirely correct. 
I should discuss the continuity, the existence of partial derivatives and the differentiability of this function on every point of its domain. 
The function is:

$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{y^3}\cdot ln(1+x^3\cdot y) \: \: \: if \: \:  y\neq 0
 &  & \\ x+|x| \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: if \: \: y=0
 &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

The domain is clearly: $domf=\left \{ (x,y)\: \in \: \mathbb{R}^2 \: : \: 1+x^3\cdot y>0) \right \}$ 
I show you my try: 
The function is differentiable $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y\neq 0 \: \: and \: \: x\neq 0$ , because it's a composition of differentiable functions. I put $x\neq 0$ cause the absolute value in the second equation will almost certainly give some problems. For these values the function is also continue and partial derivable, since its differentiable. 
We should check the continuity:
$\lim_{y \to 0}f(x,y)=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{1}{y^3}\cdot ln(1+x^3\cdot y)=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{x^3}{y^2}=\left\{\begin{matrix} +\propto \: \: if \: \: x>0
 &  & \\ 0 \: \: if \: \: x=0
 &  & \\ -\propto \: \: if \: \: x<0
 &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$
So the function is not continuous for the point of the form $(x,0)$ with $x\neq 0$, so it is not differentiable on the y-axis (except for the origin, which we'll check later).

Now I should check if the function has partial derivatives for the points of the form $(x,0)$, which I excluded before. 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+t,0)-f(x,0)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{x+t+|x+t|-x-|x|}{t}=\left\{\begin{matrix} 2 \: \: if \: \: x>0
 &  & \\ \nexists \: \: if \: \: x=0 
 &  & \\ 0 \: \: if \: \: x<0
 &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$


$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,0)}{t}=\frac{\frac{1}{t^3}\cdot ln(1+x^3\cdot t)-x-|x|}{t}=\left\{\begin{matrix}\nexists \: \: (=\pm\propto) \: \: if \: \: x\neq 0
 &  & \\ 0 \: \: if \: \: x=0
 &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$


Since $(0,0)$ doesn't admit both partial derivatives, we can conclude that the function is not differentiable in the origin. 
Can you please tell me if I solved the exercise correctly? I would really appreciate you're help. Thank you. 
P.S: Sorry if I made some english mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks mostly good but you're missing some cases.

In the line
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{y^3}\ln(1+x^3y)=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{x^3}{y^2}$$
you're using l'Hopital's rule, so you need to do both derivatives properly ($3y^2$, $(1+x^3y)^{-1}$).

You haven't mentioned points of the form $(0,y)$ yet.

You've correctly concluded that it's not differentiable at $(0,0)$, but you haven't said anything about it being continuous there. Note that continuity is pretty difficult, so even when you see $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,0)=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}f(0,y)=0$ that's not enough. You need *every* possible curve that goes to $(0,0)$ to have the same limit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually in the limit, since $x$ is a fixed value and $x\cdot y \mapsto 0 \: \: for \: \: y \mapsto 0$ I used the fact that $ln(1+x^3 \cdot y)$ is asymptotically equal to $x^3 \cdot y$, and so I obtained the limit, without applying l'hopital's rule. Yeah, you're right about the continuity in the origin $(0,0)$ ... Mabye that multi-variable limit is easier to calculate if I use polar coordinates. Tomorrow morning I'll give it a try. I really appreciate your support!